# I'm trying to get the string value of the TextView to display to charSequence

Tags: android, notifications

here is my code:

```
MyNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    String tickerText = "Hello";
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());

    String contentTitle = GetString(R.id.title);

    MyI = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LyceumWebNotification.class);

    MyPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, MyI, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Hello" , "Title: " + contentTitle, MyPI); 
    MyNM.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);


public String GetString(int id){
return ((TextView)this.findViewById(id)).getText().toString();

}
```

it is possible to get data of TextView and display as Charsequence to notification?

Comment: It is possible but if your activity is not created at that you will get NullPointerException. So its better you create a CharSequence instance separately and then set the text in it and then notify the TextView, then your GetString() method will be just returning that CharSequence instance.

Answer (score 0):

[getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29) already returns a CharSequence. Do not convert it to String